# Azure Data Factory : Recursive file copy name in the destination

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have data factory that upload daily upload file from on premise into ADLS.
Currently all the files uploaded are using directoryName-GUID as name.

For uploaded file i want to keep the same name as source file , how can i do that ?

I tired the following

```
"linkedServiceName": "Destination-DataLakeStore-gd6",
        "typeProperties": {
            "fileName": "{fileName}.csv",
            "folderPath": "data/{year}/{month}/{day}",
            "format": {
                "type": "TextFormat",
                "columnDelimiter": ","
            },
            "partitionedBy"
```

But instead of substituting the filename it is output the file as {fileName}.csv

What are my options here ?

Answer (score 0):

Do not specify filename in the datasets. Your current config actually indicate naming the file as "{fileName}.csv".

A related note: if you just want to copy files as-is without parsing it, you can skip the format setting for both input and output datasets (or keep them exactly the same).